# Animating SVG Path elements

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I've got an SVG with a few paths inside. I'd like to translate these paths about 100px down and have them fade out. I'm going to use Javascript to repeat this animation eventually. For now, I've created the CSS animations and appended the class  to each element, but it doesn't seem to work. If I view in web inspector and toggle the translate property, the animation works as expected. It doesn't seem to work on page load though.

I might be approaching this wrong, I'd really appreciate a solution.

Here's a link to the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Doomed</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #000;
        }
                    .st0 {
                fill: #FFFFFF;
            }
        .drop {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
            transform: translateY(0px);            
        }
        .drop.move {
            transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
            transform: translateY(50px);            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="umbrella_1_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 750 392" xml:space="preserve">
        <path id="umbrella_x5F_body" class="st0" d="M368.3,34.7c0.9-3.7,1.5-7.4,2.6-11.1c0.5-1.6,0.9-3.1,2-4.3c0.8-0.9,2-2,3.2-1.9
    c1.3,0.1,2.4,1.2,3.2,2.1c1,1.2,1.4,2.7,1.8,4.2c1.1,3.6,1.7,7.4,2.6,11.1c5.5,0.5,11.4,0.9,17.3,1.7c43.3,6,76.3,28.1,100.1,64.2
    c7.3,11,13.5,22.8,18.5,35c5,12.1,8.9,24.7,11.9,37.5c0.8,3.6,1.6,7.3,2.3,11c0.3,1.8,0.7,3.6,1,5.4c0.3,1.8,0.9,3.8,0.8,5.6
    c-0.1,3.6-1.7,6.6-5.6,6.8c-3.7,0.1-5.6-2.7-6-6.1c-0.6-5.1-1.3-10.3-2.9-15.2c-1.6-4.9-4.1-9.4-7.4-13.3
    c-5.9-7-13.7-12.2-22.5-14.7c-17.2-5-36.3,1-47.7,14.8c-6.2,7.5-9.8,16.8-10.3,26.5c-0.1,2,0,4.1-1.1,5.8c-0.9,1.4-2.3,2.1-3.8,2.2
    c-1.6,0.1-3.4-0.2-4.6-1.3c-1.3-1.1-1.8-2.9-1.8-4.5c-0.4-11.9-4.3-22.5-12.7-31.2c-7-7.3-15.5-11.9-26.4-13.5c0,2.3,0,4.2,0,6.1
    c0,65.1,0,130.3,0,195.4c0,2.2,0.6,4.8-0.3,6.4c-1.4,2.2-3.8,4.8-6.1,5.3c-2.2,0.5-4.3-0.6-5.4-2.6c-1.4-2.6-1-5.7-1-8.6
    c0-7.1,0-14.1,0-21.2c0-14,0-28.1,0-42.1c0-14.1,0-28.2,0-42.3c0-14,0-28.1,0-42.1c0-14.1,0-28.2,0-42.3c0-1.7,0-3.5,0-5.2
    c0-2,0-3.9,0-7.1c-4.5,1.4-8.6,2.3-12.2,4c-16.5,7.8-25.5,20.9-26.7,39.1c-0.1,1.9-0.3,3.9-1.3,5.6c-1.1,1.6-3,2.3-4.9,2.4
    c-4.3,0.1-5.3-4.6-5.5-8c-1.4-18.2-10.2-31.6-26.8-39c-16.2-7.3-31.9-5.2-46.2,5.4c-10.3,7.7-15.9,18.2-17.1,31
    c-0.2,1.8-0.5,3.6-0.8,5.4c-0.2,1.2-0.6,2.3-1.3,3.3c-1.5,1.9-4,2.2-6.2,1.6c-2.3-0.6-3.7-2.5-3.8-4.9c0-1.7,0.4-3.5,0.7-5.2
    c0.3-1.8,0.6-3.6,0.9-5.4c0.7-4.2,1.5-8.4,2.5-12.5c6-26,15.5-50.6,30.3-72.9c26.6-40.1,63.8-62.3,112.1-65.4
    C365,35.2,366.8,35.2,368.3,34.7C369.4,30,368,34.8,368.3,34.7z M424,164.7c0.5-3.9,0.9-7.8,1-11.7c0.8-23.1-0.4-46-9-67.8
    c-6.7-16.9-17.4-30.3-34.9-37c-2.5-1-6-1-8.5-0.1c-16.3,6-26.9,18-33.7,33.6c-10,22.8-11.6,47-10.5,71.5c0.1,3.2,0.5,6.5,0.8,10.2
    C354.4,130.8,400.3,132.3,424,164.7 M317.1,154.2c0.3-11.5,0-23,0.9-34.4c1.9-21.7,7.3-42.3,20.8-60c2.8-3.6,6-6.9,9.1-10.5
    C307.4,49,250,102.8,240.3,149.9c34.7-15.7,44.4-14.7,76.8,8.4 M436.5,157.5c23.7-21.4,48.8-23.7,75.8-7.5
    c-11.6-48.7-66.6-100.6-106.6-100.7C405.7,49.4,441.3,74,436.5,157.5z" />
        <path id="drop4" class="st0 drop" d="M489.5,201.3c1.9,7.5,4.2,15,5.4,22.6c0.7,4.4-0.9,11.5-6.5,11.7c-5.8,0.2-7.8-7.3-7-11.8
    c1.3-7.6,3.7-15,5.6-22.5C487.8,201.3,488.6,201.3,489.5,201.3C491.3,208.8,488.6,201.3,489.5,201.3z" />
        <path id="drop3" class="st0 drop" d="M441.6,244.8c1.8,7.8,4.1,15.6,5.2,23.5c0.4,3.1-0.3,6.5-2.6,8.7c-1.9,1.8-4.6,2.4-6.9,1.1
    c-2.6-1.5-4.1-4.5-4.2-7.4c-0.1-1.9,0.3-3.8,0.7-5.6c0.4-2.2,0.9-4.3,1.4-6.4c1.1-4.7,2.3-9.3,3.4-13.9
    C439.6,244.8,440.6,244.8,441.6,244.8C443.4,252.6,440.6,244.8,441.6,244.8z" />
        <path id="drop2" class="st0 drop" d="M340.3,231.5c1.3,5.9,2.7,11.9,4,17.8c0.3,1.4,0.6,2.8,0.9,4.3c0.3,1.6,0.7,2.9,0.3,4.4
    c-0.4,1.9-1,3.9-2.1,5.5c-2.4,3.2-7.6,2.9-9.8-0.4c-1.1-1.6-1.5-3.5-1.6-5.3c-0.2-2.8-0.1-5.5,0.4-8.3c1-6.1,3.5-11.8,5.7-17.6
    C338.9,231.7,339.6,231.6,340.3,231.5C342.2,239.6,339.6,231.6,340.3,231.5z" />
        <path id="drop1" class="st0 drop" d="M274.4,202.2c2.1,4.9,4.1,9.9,5.3,15.1c1.1,4.9,2.1,10.6-0.4,15.2c-1.8,3.3-5.8,5-9,2.2
    c-1.6-1.4-2.6-3.7-3.1-5.8c-0.5-2.5,0.3-5.2,0.9-7.7c1.3-6.4,2.9-12.8,4.3-19.2C273.1,202.1,273.7,202.2,274.4,202.2
    C277.7,210.2,273.7,202.2,274.4,202.2z" />
    </svg>
    <script>
        var drops = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');
            for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
            //works
            console.log(drops[i]);
            drops[i].classList.add('move');
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to animate each drop separately? If not, I've setup an animation with `animation` property.

**Here is a snippet**

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
.drop {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  animation: drop 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes drop {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="umbrella_1_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 750 392" xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="umbrella_x5F_body" class="st0" d="M368.3,34.7c0.9-3.7,1.5-7.4,2.6-11.1c0.5-1.6,0.9-3.1,2-4.3c0.8-0.9,2-2,3.2-1.9
    c1.3,0.1,2.4,1.2,3.2,2.1c1,1.2,1.4,2.7,1.8,4.2c1.1,3.6,1.7,7.4,2.6,11.1c5.5,0.5,11.4,0.9,17.3,1.7c43.3,6,76.3,28.1,100.1,64.2
    c7.3,11,13.5,22.8,18.5,35c5,12.1,8.9,24.7,11.9,37.5c0.8,3.6,1.6,7.3,2.3,11c0.3,1.8,0.7,3.6,1,5.4c0.3,1.8,0.9,3.8,0.8,5.6
    c-0.1,3.6-1.7,6.6-5.6,6.8c-3.7,0.1-5.6-2.7-6-6.1c-0.6-5.1-1.3-10.3-2.9-15.2c-1.6-4.9-4.1-9.4-7.4-13.3
    c-5.9-7-13.7-12.2-22.5-14.7c-17.2-5-36.3,1-47.7,14.8c-6.2,7.5-9.8,16.8-10.3,26.5c-0.1,2,0,4.1-1.1,5.8c-0.9,1.4-2.3,2.1-3.8,2.2
    c-1.6,0.1-3.4-0.2-4.6-1.3c-1.3-1.1-1.8-2.9-1.8-4.5c-0.4-11.9-4.3-22.5-12.7-31.2c-7-7.3-15.5-11.9-26.4-13.5c0,2.3,0,4.2,0,6.1
    c0,65.1,0,130.3,0,195.4c0,2.2,0.6,4.8-0.3,6.4c-1.4,2.2-3.8,4.8-6.1,5.3c-2.2,0.5-4.3-0.6-5.4-2.6c-1.4-2.6-1-5.7-1-8.6
    c0-7.1,0-14.1,0-21.2c0-14,0-28.1,0-42.1c0-14.1,0-28.2,0-42.3c0-14,0-28.1,0-42.1c0-14.1,0-28.2,0-42.3c0-1.7,0-3.5,0-5.2
    c0-2,0-3.9,0-7.1c-4.5,1.4-8.6,2.3-12.2,4c-16.5,7.8-25.5,20.9-26.7,39.1c-0.1,1.9-0.3,3.9-1.3,5.6c-1.1,1.6-3,2.3-4.9,2.4
    c-4.3,0.1-5.3-4.6-5.5-8c-1.4-18.2-10.2-31.6-26.8-39c-16.2-7.3-31.9-5.2-46.2,5.4c-10.3,7.7-15.9,18.2-17.1,31
    c-0.2,1.8-0.5,3.6-0.8,5.4c-0.2,1.2-0.6,2.3-1.3,3.3c-1.5,1.9-4,2.2-6.2,1.6c-2.3-0.6-3.7-2.5-3.8-4.9c0-1.7,0.4-3.5,0.7-5.2
    c0.3-1.8,0.6-3.6,0.9-5.4c0.7-4.2,1.5-8.4,2.5-12.5c6-26,15.5-50.6,30.3-72.9c26.6-40.1,63.8-62.3,112.1-65.4
    C365,35.2,366.8,35.2,368.3,34.7C369.4,30,368,34.8,368.3,34.7z M424,164.7c0.5-3.9,0.9-7.8,1-11.7c0.8-23.1-0.4-46-9-67.8
    c-6.7-16.9-17.4-30.3-34.9-37c-2.5-1-6-1-8.5-0.1c-16.3,6-26.9,18-33.7,33.6c-10,22.8-11.6,47-10.5,71.5c0.1,3.2,0.5,6.5,0.8,10.2
    C354.4,130.8,400.3,132.3,424,164.7 M317.1,154.2c0.3-11.5,0-23,0.9-34.4c1.9-21.7,7.3-42.3,20.8-60c2.8-3.6,6-6.9,9.1-10.5
    C307.4,49,250,102.8,240.3,149.9c34.7-15.7,44.4-14.7,76.8,8.4 M436.5,157.5c23.7-21.4,48.8-23.7,75.8-7.5
    c-11.6-48.7-66.6-100.6-106.6-100.7C405.7,49.4,441.3,74,436.5,157.5z" />
  <path id="drop4" class="st0 drop" d="M489.5,201.3c1.9,7.5,4.2,15,5.4,22.6c0.7,4.4-0.9,11.5-6.5,11.7c-5.8,0.2-7.8-7.3-7-11.8
    c1.3-7.6,3.7-15,5.6-22.5C487.8,201.3,488.6,201.3,489.5,201.3C491.3,208.8,488.6,201.3,489.5,201.3z" />
  <path id="drop3" class="st0 drop" d="M441.6,244.8c1.8,7.8,4.1,15.6,5.2,23.5c0.4,3.1-0.3,6.5-2.6,8.7c-1.9,1.8-4.6,2.4-6.9,1.1
    c-2.6-1.5-4.1-4.5-4.2-7.4c-0.1-1.9,0.3-3.8,0.7-5.6c0.4-2.2,0.9-4.3,1.4-6.4c1.1-4.7,2.3-9.3,3.4-13.9
    C439.6,244.8,440.6,244.8,441.6,244.8C443.4,252.6,440.6,244.8,441.6,244.8z" />
  <path id="drop2" class="st0 drop" d="M340.3,231.5c1.3,5.9,2.7,11.9,4,17.8c0.3,1.4,0.6,2.8,0.9,4.3c0.3,1.6,0.7,2.9,0.3,4.4
    c-0.4,1.9-1,3.9-2.1,5.5c-2.4,3.2-7.6,2.9-9.8-0.4c-1.1-1.6-1.5-3.5-1.6-5.3c-0.2-2.8-0.1-5.5,0.4-8.3c1-6.1,3.5-11.8,5.7-17.6
    C338.9,231.7,339.6,231.6,340.3,231.5C342.2,239.6,339.6,231.6,340.3,231.5z" />
  <path id="drop1" class="st0 drop" d="M274.4,202.2c2.1,4.9,4.1,9.9,5.3,15.1c1.1,4.9,2.1,10.6-0.4,15.2c-1.8,3.3-5.8,5-9,2.2
    c-1.6-1.4-2.6-3.7-3.1-5.8c-0.5-2.5,0.3-5.2,0.9-7.7c1.3-6.4,2.9-12.8,4.3-19.2C273.1,202.1,273.7,202.2,274.4,202.2
    C277.7,210.2,273.7,202.2,274.4,202.2z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting this working! I would like to animate them individually, but that should be a pretty pretty simple to accomplish with some Javascript :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Yep, you could call the animation within a class like `drop-down` and  trigger this class within JS with an increasing time interval.